# WP_Query posts_per_page ignored

Tags: posts, wp-query, limit

I struggle already for a few hours with the `posts_per_page` ignored in my `WP_Query` :

```
[query] => Array
(
    [post_type] => Array
        (
        )

    [posts_per_page] => 4
    [meta_key] => _touchsize_likes
    [orderby] => meta_value_num
    [order] => DESC
)
```

The result has `found_posts = 18` and `12` posts in the `posts` array.

Even if the only parameter set is `posts_per_page`, the results are wrong.

Checked the `query_vars['post_type']`, the value is 4. Tried with `suppress_filters => true`, still no effect.

Any idea ?

Comment: Poorly written `pre_get_posts` action in a plugin or in your theme

Comment: @PieterGoosen, Checked the `pre_get_posts` and everything was fine :) The problem was the missing `ignore_sticky_posts` parameter, though I don't think it's the right way to work.

Comment: Jip, that also explains your issue. Sticky posts are simply added on top of the actual queried posts. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It were the sticky posts who ignored my `posts_per_page`. After setting `'ignore_sticky_posts' => true` the result was correct !

Comment: That is not totally true. The sticky posts doesn't make **`posts_per_page` be ignored**, what is happening is that sticky posts are always added to the top of the actual query but not into it. So it may be possible that you get more posts in the first page than the number you have set in `posts_per_page` argument, but it is not being ignored. That is how it is designed and how it is explained in codex.